# How to debug the argument problem in Linux at the bash

Tags: linux

The question is contents of the variable $TEST are equal to the string “success, or the
number 5 or the contents of the variable $RESULT

The code that I write is  [ $TEST=”success” -o $TEST -eq ”5”  -o  $TEST = “$RESULT” ], but when in the linux there saying that bash: [ too many argument. Can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need || for this, to represent or and so:

```
if [[ "$TEST"==”success” || "$TEST"==”5” || "$TEST" == “$RESULT” ]]
then
      echo "match"
else
      echo "No match"
fi
```

Comment: If in the terminal form, cause my question it advise me using -o, but not ||

Comment: Can you add some more detail on what you are trying to do?

Comment: the full question is the contents of the variable $TEST are equal to the string “success, or the number 5 or the contents of the variable $RESULT